# Should you worry about high voltage and wattage on a non-overclocked computer?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, fan, temperature, voltage

I've been wondering if I should be worried at all about high wattage or voltage on a non-overclocked computer. I say non-overclocked because when I Google search this question or something similar it comes up with results for safe voltage/wattage on an overclocked CPU or some such, but not for a non-overclocked one. I've got [this](https://i.imgur.com/vTpP2KT.png) screenshot and [this](https://i.imgur.com/O1kScN4.png) one (you should be able to get my graphics card and CPU models off those two screenshots). After playing Civ 5 and Dota 2, respectively (the maxes are what worries me, these screenshots were taken after closing out the games). Is there anything I should be worried about in those two screenshots, or is everything perfectly fine (in terms of just about *everything*; wattage, fan RPM, PWM %, temperatures, etc)? Computer still works fine, etc. Only thing is that I hear a slight buzzing/static sound when playing certain games in my headphones as well as when doing most anything on my computer, but it's loudest when playing games. Not too obstructively loud, but still noticeable unless I have some song playing in the background. I'm assuming this is a product of electrical interference with the headphones due to the wattage/voltage rising whenever I do something, but I could be wrong. The general static I hear outside of playing games has been there since the day I first turned on the computer, but as I said, it does get noticeably louder in certain games (I believe Civ 5 is when it's been most noticeable). For Dota 2 in particular, I'm using the NVIDIA GeForce Experience's recommended "optimal" graphical settings.

Comment: Are your headphones connected to the motherboards audio?

Comment: @LittleHelper They're plugged into the front headphone port. [Here's](http://doxz7msmg7sxx.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/7/image/2432x1368/c2f10b1d8f5a5ddacfb442b817d0e244/1/_/1_7849_1_1_1_3.jpg) a picture of my computer (ASUS M51AD. Headphones are plugged into the headphone port at the top right there, not sure if that's the motherboard's audio or what. I believe it has some ports in the back, too, but I doubt my headphones could reach that far. The headphones work perfectly fine on other devices, so I doubt there's something wrong with my headphones.

Comment: Probably those jacks are connected to motherboards audio, and onboard audio usually is the one to blame for buzzing/static sounds.  That's another reason why audio cards exist because their power is seperatted from motherboard's power (in some way). I'm also experiencing such issue but only in some cases (for example, one is when I have in-line audio jack connected). If you are worried about voltages, you can always run stress tests to be secure and if they fail at some moment, then you should be worried and do something about it like lowering the voltage. But now, readings look safe.

Comment: I'm assuming onboard audio and motherboard audio are the same thing? I'd rather not run stress tests, seems like asking for trouble and not worth it under the current circumstances. If you say those readings are safe right now, I think things should be fine. The computer's only a couple months old, I'd be mad if I had to manually lower the voltage or wattage right now. What do you mean by the voltages failing? Just the computer shutting down or what? Asking so I can have some ideas as to what to watch out for.

Comment: Sorry, english is mine third language. What I meant by motherboards audio was onboard audio (same thing). And I meant that if the stress tests fail, then something should be done like lowering voltage or clock speed. Those readings are very good. GPU max temperature was 77°C (GPUs can survive at 100°C so nothing to worry about here). All you have to do in order to maintain your computer is just to check for dust time to time (I clean my PC once a month, sometimes once in 2 months but that's because I live in such environment), but I assume your computer probably has filters for intake fans.

Comment: It's fine. From a native english speaker to you, your english is great! Anyway, yeah, my computer has filters for intake fans. Thanks for all your help!